# Nested re-evaluation of rules and checkpoints in snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm trying to set up a workflow where when given a file `FIRST`, the file is split to  $k$ separate files **where k is unknown**,`SECOND_1, SECOND_2,...,SECOND_k` for parallel processing.

Each file `SECOND_i` (i=1...k) is then processed to produce additional i_n files, that is, at the end of the process, we are going to have 1_n files for  `SECOND_1`, 2_n for `SECOND_2` and so on, where, again, the numbers i_n are unknown and distinct.

This step produces a set of files `THIRD_ij` where i=1...k and j=1...i_n.

Now I wish to merge (`cat`) all files with the same index j, to get the files `FOURTH_1, FOURTH_2,...,FOURTH_m`
where `FOURTH_2` for example is a concatenation of all files `THIRD_i2` that exists.

I've tried to do so using snakemake, but I get some weird errors.

My current code looks like this

```py
rule split1:
    input: "FIRST"
    output: "first.done"
    shell: 
        "[splitting_function1] {input} ;"
        "touch {output}"

checkpoint split2:
    input: "SECOND_{i}"
    output: "{i}/second.done"
    shell: 
        "[splitting_function2] {input} ; # makes a subdirectory {i} with the output"
        "touch {output}"

def aggregate(wildcards):
    out = checkpoints.split2.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    out = out.replace("second.out","")
    exp = expand(
            "{i}/THIRD_{{j}}",
            i= glob_wildcards(os.path.join(out, "THIRD_{j}")).i,
            j = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(out, "THIRD_{j}")).j
        )

rule merge:
    input: aggregate
    output: "{j}/third.done"
    shell: 
        "cat {input} > {j}/FOURTH ;"
        "touch {output}"
```

I keep getting `WorkflowError`s and missing wildcard values for i. I'd love to figure this out!

Comment: Try working up the snakefile from final outputs to inputs (FOURTH from THIRD, then THIRD from SECOND).  I will guess you need additional rules and cascading checkpoints.  Based on the github and stackoverflow issues you may run into some problems with chaining checkpoints.